# Why do many standard implementations allow a value to be directly assigned to an ostream_iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, iostream

All the standard implementations I have tried allow values to be assigned to the `std::ostream_iterator`'s without having them dereferenced before the assignment. Although the standard algorithms dereference the iterators before the assignment, I would like to know why there are implementations that don't just forbid the assignment statically (with the help of a proxy class) so that the compilation would just fail, so that the user knows something wrong might happen if such assignment is ported to another implementation not allowing the assignment for some reasons.
In general, when implementing a standard functionality, is it a good practice to limit the implementation to only allow what is explicitly mentioned by the standard?

```
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ostream_iterator<string> o(cout);
    o = "Hello World\n"; // o is not dereferenced! It compiles with my GCC environment
    o++; // to make sure the implementation writes to cout
}
```

Comment: `In general, when implementing a standard functionality, is it a good practice to limit the implementation to only allow what is explicitly mentioned by the standard?` Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator overload that allows this assignment is specified by the C++ language standard.  Thus, a C++ Standard Library implementation must provide it.

The overload is specified as follows (from C++11 §24.6.2.2/1):

> ```
> ostream_iterator& operator=(const T& value);
> ```
>
> Effects:
>
> ```
> *out_stream << value;
> if(delim != 0)
>     *out_stream << delim;
>
> return (*this);
> ```

(`T` is the `T` with which the `ostream_iterator` was instantiated.  In your example, it is `string`.)

Answer (score 1):

Stream iterators are really just fake iterators. The insertion happens when assigning for `ostream_iterator` and the extraction happens when dereferencing for `istream_iterator`. The `operator*()` for `ostream_iterator` is actually specified as a no-op to just return `*this`.